# Error publishing a plugin for Custom Plugin upload

Tags: android, plugins, jetbrains-ide

I have created one custom plugin and works well in testing mode.

I need to upload my plugin in JetBrains,
So I have created the zip file and upload it.

I got the following error while uploading the zip file.

Can anyone help to fix this?[image]